# C# WebBrowser different html document after navigate

Tags: c#, html, document, reload

I have a really strange problem in C#:

First I use the WebBrowser control and the navigate method to browse.
wb_email.Navigate("https://registrierung.web.de");

Now I can change the innerText of htmlelements without any problems.
wb_email.Document.GetElementById("id4").InnerText = "Alexander";

But when I reload the page by simply using the navigate method with the same url again,
I get a null exception. It seems as he can't find the element.

So I used an inspector for Firefox to see if the htmlelement really changed, after reloading.
But only the url is changing, htmlelements are all the same.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're just changing the DOM in the displayed page.  When you reload the page, the `WebBrowser` instance will just refresh the DOM from the server again and lose your changes.

The `WebBrowser` class isn't designed for editing rendered pages inside itself, as it's basically just a wrapper to an embedded Internet Explorer instance.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want. Lose all changes and begin from new.

Comment: But how can I access the htmlelements after I navigated to the same page again?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the website has finished loading before accessing any element. Like:

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_DocumentCompleted);

void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Access elements here
}
```